# Valor de n no algoritmo do Xadrez de Malba Tahan

Tags: c, algoritmo

Eu estou em dúvida quanto ao valor de n no código, no "for" a seguir 1 é atribuído ao valor de n, sendo assim não seria para na primeira iteração o valor de n ser 2?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
  float n=0;
  int v=0;


  for(n=1;n>=0 && v!=64;n=n+n){
    v++;
    printf("%i° Quad. tem %.0f grãos\n",v,n );
  }
}
```

Comment: se atribuiu 1, como ele poderia ser 2 na primeira interação? isso não faz o menor sentido

Comment: na soma n = n + n, n vale 1 então o valor seria 2 não seria?

Comment: Quanto ao "for", o bloco só é executado depois do printf ? Se for assim faz sentido o n valer 1 pois foi exibido na primeira iteração, seria isso?

Comment: O comando for funciona da seguinte maneira: `for (valor inicial; condição para continuar no loop; incremento)` no caso o `incremento` é executado ao final do bloco, como se fosse o último comando. A condição é avaliada a cada início do bloco e o valor inicial uma única vez. Aliás a maneira tradicional de fazer tal incremento em C seria: `n*=2`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, minha duvida foi sanada!